# How to increase the size of a variable using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I have an XSLT file that contains the following attribute set

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="related-links__content">
    <xsl:attribute name="start-indent"><xsl:value-of select="$side-col-width"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

The value of `$side-col-width` is a number with a unit (such as `24pt`).

What I need to do is increase this value by a specific about. Semantically, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
<!-- Obviously not correct -->
<xsl:attribute-set name="related-links__content">
    <xsl:attribute name="start-indent">
        <xsl:value-of select="$side-col-width"/> + 12pt
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

Is this something that is possible with XSLT, and if so how can it be done?

Comment: Do you know the exact structure of `$side-col-width`? For example, is it always some digits followed by "pt" - or can the units change? In fact, why don't you show us how  `$side-col-width` gets populated?

Comment: $side-col-width is set manually. It should always be in pts (so yes it will always be some digits followed by "pt"). I'm OK with a solution that expects this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $side-col-width is set manually.

I am not quite sure what you mean by "set manually". If you have something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="side-col-width" select="'24pt'"/>
```

then:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($side-col-width, 'pt') + 12, 'pt')"/>
```

will return `36pt`.

Whether that's the best workflow to have is another question.

Comment: This works only if I use number() convert the string to a number first: `number(substring-before($side-col-width, 'pt')) + 12 ...`

Comment: That probably means you're using XSLT 2.0. For future reference: always tell us which version of XSLT you are using.

Comment: "*This works only if I use number() convert the string to a number first*" It shouldn't be necessary, because attempting to use the string in an addition should convert it to a number implicitly (tested in Xalan, libxslt and Saxon 6.5 and 9). Which processor are you using?